# Excluir valores da lista de opções em html

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tenho uma página e exibo 4 opções para cada uma das 4 alternativas. Sendo cada opção um valor de 1 a 4.

Gostaria que cada vez que o usuário selecionasse um valor, este valor fosse excluído da lista de opções das outras alternativas, forçando o usuário a não repetir os valores para cada alternativa.

Código com as alternativas e opções em html:

```
<body>
    <h1>Avalie de 1 a 4 sem repetir</h1>
    <div id="p1">
        <form id="form1" action="" method="get">
            <label class="control-label" for="a1"> <strong> Organizado</strong></label>
            <select name="a1">
                <option  id="a1" name="a1" value="4" /> 4<br />
                <option  id="a1" name="a1" value="3" /> 3<br />
                <option  id="a1" name="a1" value="2" /> 2<br />
                <option  id="a1" name="a1" value="1" /> 1<br />
            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <label class="control-label" for="b1"> <strong> Criativo</strong></label>
            <select name="b1">
                <option  id="b1" name="b1" value="4" /> 4<br />
                <option  id="b1" name="b1" value="3" /> 3<br />
                <option  id="b1" name="b1" value="2" /> 2<br />
                <option  id="b1" name="b1" value="1" /> 1<br />
            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <label class="control-label" for="c1"> <strong> Independente</strong></label>
            <select name="c1">
                <option  id="c1" name="c1" value="4" /> 4<br />
                <option  id="c1" name="c1" value="3" /> 3<br />
                <option  id="c1" name="c1" value="2" /> 2<br />
                <option  id="c1" name="c1" value="1" /> 1<br />
            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <label class="control-label" for="d1"> <strong> Impulsivo</strong></label>
            <select name="d1">
                <option  id="d1" name="d1" value="4" /> 4<br />
                <option  id="d1" name="d1" value="3" /> 3<br />
                <option  id="d1" name="d1" value="2" /> 2<br />
                <option  id="d1" name="d1" value="1" /> 1<br />
            </select>
            <br />

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Olá Bruno. Isso é um problema interessante e meio complexo. Dá uma olhada aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/hghv56ks/ Como queres que aconteça depois de os 4 selects terem sido selecionados uma vez, e querendo mudar os valores de novo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você não mencionou se está usando **jQuery** ou outra library, vou colocar um exemplo em puro javascript:

Primeiro, aplicar o evento onchange em todos os select:

```
<select name="a1" id="a1" onchange="valorSelecionado(this)">
```

Depois, a function para verificar o valor selecionado e remover dos outros select:

```
function valorSelecionado(sel) {
  var val = sel.selectedIndex;
  var id = sel.id;

  var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
  for(var i = 0; i < selects.length; ++i) {
    var s = selects[i];
    if (s.id != id) {
       s.removeChild(s[val])
    }
  } 
}
```

Aqui um exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/jcsj9ddz/

Comment: Olá Ricardo, podes juntar um exemplo de este código em funcionamento?

Comment: @Sergio sim, editei o comentário

Comment: Boa, assim fica mais claro. Leste [o meu comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159770/excluir-valores-da-lista-de-op%c3%a7%c3%b5es-em-html/159785?noredirect=1#comment328830_159770) em cima? esse problema fica ainda por resolver. Na tua resposta fica também irreversível voltar a colocar as opções removidas. Acho que era melhor uma abordagem mais suave.

Comment: Sim, o melhor seria ter um objeto com as opções para poder reverter (adicionar novamente se necessário). Outra coisa, uma vez que o usuário selecionou uma opção, aquele select deveria ser desabilitado (na minha opinião), para evitar selecionar outro item e remover dos outros selects, ou seja, nesse código, se o usuário selecionar 3 valores diferentes no primeiro select (selecionar cada valor de uma vez), estes valores vão sumir dos demais selects, isso é ruim :)

Comment: É verdade amigos, o problema é que daí não é possível modificar a resposta caso o usuario tenha inserido errado.

Comment: De qualquer forma obrigado essa ajuda ja deu pra dar uma clareada

Comment: Ok, não esqueça de votar na resposta se ela foi útil.